# cant install get_cli i guess error is with posix package and pwd.dart

Tags: flutter, dart, posix, flutter-getx, get-cli

```
Building package executables... (24.4s)
Failed to build get_cli:get:
AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/posix-4.1.0/lib/src/pwd.dart:322:35: Error: Field 'name' cannot be nullable or have type 'Null', it must be `int`, `double`, `Pointer`, or a subtype of `Struct` or `Union`.
  external ffi.Pointer<ffi.Int8>? name;
                                  ^
AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/posix-4.1.0/lib/src/pwd.dart:326:35: Error: Field 'password' cannot be nullable or have type 'Null', it must be `int`, `double`, `Pointer`, or a subtype of `Struct` or `Union`.
  external ffi.Pointer<ffi.Int8>? password;
                                  ^
AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/posix-4.1.0/lib/src/pwd.dart:330:17: Error: Field 'uid' cannot be nullable or have type 'Null', it must be `int`, `double`, `Pointer`, or a subtype of `Struct` or `Union`.
  external int? uid;
                ^
AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/posix-4.1.0/lib/src/pwd.dart:334:17: Error: Field 'gid' cannot be nullable or have type 'Null', it must be `int`, `double`, `Pointer`, or a subtype of `Struct` or `Union`.
  external int? gid;
                ^
AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/posix-4.1.0/lib/src/pwd.dart:337:35: Error: Field 'gecos' cannot be nullable or have type 'Null', it must be `int`, `double`, `Pointer`, or a subtype of `Struct` or `Union`.
  external ffi.Pointer<ffi.Int8>? gecos;
                                  ^
AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/posix-4.1.0/lib/src/pwd.dart:340:35: Error: Field 'dir' cannot be nullable or have type 'Null', it must be `int`, `double`, `Pointer`, or a subtype of `Struct` or `Union`.
  external ffi.Pointer<ffi.Int8>? dir;
                                  ^
AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/posix-4.1.0/lib/src/pwd.dart:343:35: Error: Field 'shell' cannot be nullable or have type 'Null', it must be `int`, `double`, `Pointer`, or a subtype of `Struct` or `Union`.
  external ffi.Pointer<ffi.Int8>? shell;
                                  ^
AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/posix-4.1.0/lib/src/grp.dart:369:35: Error: Field 'name' cannot be nullable or have type 'Null', it must be `int`, `double`, `Pointer`, or a subtype of `Struct` or `Union`.
  external ffi.Pointer<ffi.Int8>? name;
                                  ^
AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/posix-4.1.0/lib/src/grp.dart:372:35: Error: Field 'passwd' cannot be nullable or have type 'Null', it must be `int`, `double`, `Pointer`, or a subtype of `Struct` or `Union`.
  external ffi.Pointer<ffi.Int8>? passwd;
                                  ^
AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/posix-4.1.0/lib/src/grp.dart:376:17: Error: Field 'gid' cannot be nullable or have type 'Null', it must be `int`, `double`, `Pointer`, or a subtype of `Struct` or `Union`.
  external int? gid;
                ^
AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/posix-4.1.0/lib/src/grp.dart:379:48: Error: Field 'mem' cannot be nullable or have type 'Null', it must be `int`, `double`, `Pointer`, or a subtype of `Struct` or `Union`.
  external ffi.Pointer<ffi.Pointer<ffi.Int8>>? mem;
                                               ^
AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/posix-4.1.0/lib/src/string/string.dart:830:38: Error: Field '_unique___locales_item_0' cannot be nullable or have type 'Null', it must be `int`, `double`, `Pointer`, or a subtype of `Struct` or `Union`.
  external ffi.Pointer<locale_data>? _unique___locales_item_0;
                                     ^
AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/posix-4.1.0/lib/src/string/string.dart:832:38: Error: Field '_unique___locales_item_1' cannot be nullable or have type 'Null', it must be `int`, `double`, `Pointer`, or a subtype of `Struct` or `Union`.
  external ffi.Pointer<locale_data>? _unique___locales_item_1;
                                     ^
AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/posix-4.1.0/lib/src/string/string.dart:834:38: Error: Field '_unique___locales_item_2' cannot be nullable or have type 'Null', it must be `int`, `double`, `Pointer`, or a subtype of `Struct` or `Union`.
  external ffi.Pointer<locale_data>? _unique___locales_item_2;
                                     ^
AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/posix-4.1.0/lib/src/string/string.dart:836:38: Error: Field '_unique___locales_item_3' cannot be nullable or have type 'Null', it must be `int`, `double`, `Pointer`, or a subtype of `Struct` or `Union`.
  external ffi.Pointer<locale_data>? _unique___locales_item_3;
                                     ^
AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/posix-4.1.0/lib/src/string/string.dart:838:38: Error: Field '_unique___locales_item_4' cannot be nullable or have type 'Null', it must be `int`, `double`, `Pointer`, or a subtype of `Struct` or `Union`.
  external ffi.Pointer<locale_data>? _unique___locales_item_4;
                                     ^
AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/posix-4.1.0/lib/src/string/string.dart:840:38: Error: Field '_unique___locales_item_5' cannot be nullable or have type 'Null', it must be `int`, `double`, `Pointer`, or a subtype of `Struct` or `Union`.
  external ffi.Pointer<locale_data>? _unique___locales_item_5;
                                     ^
AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/posix-4.1.0/lib/src/string/string.dart:842:38: Error: Field '_unique___locales_item_6' cannot be nullable or have type 'Null', it must be `int`, `double`, `Pointer`, or a subtype of `Struct` or `Union`.
  external ffi.Pointer<locale_data>? _unique___locales_item_6;
                                     ^
AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/posix-4.1.0/lib/src/string/string.dart:844:38: Error: Field '_unique___locales_item_7' cannot be nullable or have type 'Null', it must be `int`, `double`, `Pointer`, or a subtype of `Struct` or `Union`.
  external ffi.Pointer<locale_data>? _unique___locales_item_7;
                                     ^
AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/posix-4.1.0/lib/src/string/string.dart:846:38: Error: Field '_unique___locales_item_8' cannot be nullable or have type 'Null', it must be `int`, `double`, `Pointer`, or a subtype of `Struct` or `Union`.
  external ffi.Pointer<locale_data>? _unique___locales_item_8;
                                     ^
AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/posix-4.1.0/lib/src/string/string.dart:848:38: Error: Field '_unique___locales_item_9' cannot be nullable or have type 'Null', it must be `int`, `double`, `Pointer`, or a subtype of `Struct` or `Union`.
  external ffi.Pointer<locale_data>? _unique___locales_item_9;
                                     ^
AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/posix-4.1.0/lib/src/string/string.dart:850:38: Error: Field '_unique___locales_item_10' cannot be nullable or have type 'Null', it must be `int`, `double`, `Pointer`, or a subtype of `Struct` or `Union`.
  external ffi.Pointer<locale_data>? _unique___locales_item_10;
                                     ^
AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/posix-4.1.0/lib/src/string/string.dart:852:38: Error: Field '_unique___locales_item_11' cannot be nullable or have type 'Null', it must be `int`, `double`, `Pointer`, or a subtype of `Struct` or `Union`.
  external ffi.Pointer<locale_data>? _unique___locales_item_11;
                                     ^
AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/posix-4.1.0/lib/src/string/string.dart:854:38: Error: Field '_unique___locales_item_12' cannot be nullable or have type 'Null', it must be `int`, `double`, `Pointer`, or a subtype of `Struct` or `Union`.
  external ffi.Pointer<locale_data>? _unique___locales_item_12;
                                     ^
AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/posix-4.1.0/lib/src/string/string.dart:861:35: Error: Field '_unique___names_item_0' cannot be nullable or have type 'Null', it must be `int`, `double`, `Pointer`, or a subtype of `Struct` or `Union`.
  external ffi.Pointer<ffi.Int8>? _unique___names_item_0;
                                  ^
AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/posix-4.1.0/lib/src/string/string.dart:863:35: Error: Field '_unique___names_item_1' cannot be nullable or have type 'Null', it must be `int`, `double`, `Pointer`, or a subtype of `Struct` or `Union`.
  external ffi.Pointer<ffi.Int8>? _unique___names_item_1;
                                  ^
AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/posix-4.1.0/lib/src/string/string.dart:865:35: Error: Field '_unique___names_item_2' cannot be nullable or have type 'Null', it must be `int`, `double`, `Pointer`, or a subtype of `Struct` or `Union`.
  external ffi.Pointer<ffi.Int8>? _unique___names_item_2;
                                  ^
AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/posix-4.1.0/lib/src/string/string.dart:867:35: Error: Field '_unique___names_item_3' cannot be nullable or have type 'Null', it must be `int`, `double`, `Pointer`, or a subtype of `Struct` or `Union`.
  external ffi.Pointer<ffi.Int8>? _unique___names_item_3;
                                  ^
AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/posix-4.1.0/lib/src/string/string.dart:869:35: Error: Field '_unique___names_item_4' cannot be nullable or have type 'Null', it must be `int`, `double`, `Pointer`, or a subtype of `Struct` or `Union`.
  external ffi.Pointer<ffi.Int8>? _unique___names_item_4;
                                  ^
AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/posix-4.1.0/lib/src/string/string.dart:871:35: Error: Field '_unique___names_item_5' cannot be nullable or have type 'Null', it must be `int`, `double`, `Pointer`, or a subtype of `Struct` or `Union`.
  external ffi.Pointer<ffi.Int8>? _unique___names_item_5;
                                  ^
AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/posix-4.1.0/lib/src/string/string.dart:873:35: Error: Field '_unique___names_item_6' cannot be nullable or have type 'Null', it must be `int`, `double`, `Pointer`, or a subtype of `Struct` or `Union`.
  external ffi.Pointer<ffi.Int8>? _unique___names_item_6;
                                  ^
AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/posix-4.1.0/lib/src/string/string.dart:875:35: Error: Field '_unique___names_item_7' cannot be nullable or have type 'Null', it must be `int`, `double`, `Pointer`, or a subtype of `Struct` or `Union`.
  external ffi.Pointer<ffi.Int8>? _unique___names_item_7;
                                  ^
AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/posix-4.1.0/lib/src/string/string.dart:877:35: Error: Field '_unique___names_item_8' cannot be nullable or have type 'Null', it must be `int`, `double`, `Pointer`, or a subtype of `Struct` or `Union`.
  external ffi.Pointer<ffi.Int8>? _unique___names_item_8;
                                  ^
AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/posix-4.1.0/lib/src/string/string.dart:879:35: Error: Field '_unique___names_item_9' cannot be nullable or have type 'Null', it must be `int`, `double`, `Pointer`, or a subtype of `Struct` or `Union`.
  external ffi.Pointer<ffi.Int8>? _unique___names_item_9;
                                  ^
AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/posix-4.1.0/lib/src/string/string.dart:881:35: Error: Field '_unique___names_item_10' cannot be nullable or have type 'Null', it must be `int`, `double`, `Pointer`, or a subtype of `Struct` or `Union`.
  external ffi.Pointer<ffi.Int8>? _unique___names_item_10;
                                  ^
AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/posix-4.1.0/lib/src/string/string.dart:883:35: Error: Field '_unique___names_item_11' cannot be nullable or have type 'Null', it must be `int`, `double`, `Pointer`, or a subtype of `Struct` or `Union`.
  external ffi.Pointer<ffi.Int8>? _unique___names_item_11;
                                  ^
AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/posix-4.1.0/lib/src/string/string.dart:885:35: Error: Field '_unique___names_item_12' cannot be nullable or have type 'Null', it must be `int`, `double`, `Pointer`, or a subtype of `Struct` or `Union`.
  external ffi.Pointer<ffi.Int8>? _unique___names_item_12;
                                  ^
PS C:\Users\Admin> dart pub cache clean
This will remove everything inside C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache.
You will have to run `dart pub get` again in each project.
Are you sure? (y/N)?
PS C:\Users\Admin> dart pub cache clean
This will remove everything inside C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache.
You will have to run `dart pub get` again in each project.
Are you sure? (y/N)? y
Removing pub cache directory C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache.
PS C:\Users\Admin> dart pub global activate get_cli@1.8.0
Not a valid package name: "get_cli@1.8.0"
```

I am not founding any solution for this problem on internet but i tried to update dart package flutter package but nothing worked. So i need help to resolve this issue

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

flutter pub global activate get_cli 1.8.1
Try this version, solved for me